# Can I have an array of objects with a custom toString in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary, functional-programming

I've got an array of objects. (Use case might be solitaire cards).

I want to embed a toString for debugging them.

I'm using the following (simplified) to create them and put them into an array.

```
var shuffledArray = [];
var myObj = {
  a: "my val-a1",
  b: "my val-b1",
  init: function() {
    this.toString = this.a + " of " + this.b;
    return this;
  }
}.init();

shuffledArray.push(myObj);

var myObj2 = {
  a: "my val-a2",
  b: "my val-b2",
  init: function() {
    this.toString = this.a + " of " + this.b;
    return this;
  }
}.init();

shuffledArray.push(myObj2);

mappableToString = function (element) {
  return element.toString;
}

var shuffledArrayToString = shuffledArray.map(mappableToString); 

console.log("shuffled array: " + shuffledArrayToString.join(", "));
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong with the map step. Can't I just `join` on the `toString` method?

**Assumptions**:

- I'm aiming to use raw Javascript but am open to Underscore or JQuery.

Comment: Your code works, are you expecting a different result? ( https://jsfiddle.net/uw12xxyp/1/)

Comment: I'm concerned I'm not using the best pattern - or have missed something that makes it more complex.

Comment: The "functional" way to do this would be to create functions `toString` and `concat` that defer to the argument's method of the same name (or the correct infix operator), then do `.map(toString).reduce(concat)` FWIW, I find what you wrote to be more readable idiomatic JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [overwrite the default `toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Overriding_the_default_toString_method) with a custom method (and not a property):

```js
function MyObject(x) {
  this.x = x;
}
MyObject.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "MyObject: " + this.x;
}


var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.push(new MyObject(i));
}

console.log(arr.join(", "));
```